# SQL Take values from columns and split to columns. Thereafter combine with another table

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have two tables. The first table has a column with a lot of different values that I want to break up into several columns when showing the result. Then I would like to combine these results with table two:

Notice that table one has hourly values while table two only has dates whith time equal to `00:00:00`.

**Table 1**

```
+---------------------+------+----+
| DateAndTime         | Area | V1 |
+---------------------+------+----+
| 2012-01-01 00:00:00 | A1   | 3  |
| 2012-01-01 00:01:00 | A1   | 4  |
| 2012-01-01 00:00:00 | A2   | 4  |
| 2012-01-01 00:01:00 | A2   | 2  |
+---------------------+------+----+
```

I would like to split the area columns into several columns, and thereafter combine with table 2 based on date.

**Table 2**

```
+---------------------+----+
| DateAndTime         | V2 |
+---------------------+----+
| 2012-01-01 00:00:00 | 3  |
| 2012-01-02 00:00:00 | 4  |
+---------------------+----+
```

I would like to have the end result to be printed like this:

```
+---------------------+----+----+----+
| DateAndTime         | A1 | A2 | V2 |
+---------------------+----+----+----+
| 2012-01-01 00:00:00 | 3  | 4  | 3  |
| 2012-01-01 00:01:00 | 4  | 2  | 4  |
+---------------------+----+----+----+
```

There can be several area values (`A1`, `A2`, `A3`, ...) and the data above is simplified to make my point :)

I hope I am not double posting and that someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve here is a transposition of the different values of Area.

It's decently possible with a fixed and limited number of them but if this number is not bounded then you simply **can't** do it in **MySQL** and will have to rely on your application layer to do it :(

Drop a comment if you wan't a theorical example on how it is possible :)

Comment: Oracle supports doing this dynamically - all in SQL - but i dont think mysql does...

Comment: Woot, I honestly don't know for Oracle, but I'm really certain for MySQL. I'll edit my answer to avoid misunderstandings, thanks Randy !

Comment: I forgot to accept your answer. Sorry about that! I ended up doing it in R instead.